# RMS and probability of steady values

Tags: probability, rms

Given an RMS value of a signal/waveform/list of numbers, I would like to construct an equation that calculates the probability that $n$ consecutive points are the same (or close). Suppose I have a signal with an RMS value of 2. Is there a way to determine the probability that the signal will remain steady (i.e. within certain bounds—let's say ±0.5 to account for rounding to integers) over a certain number of points? Is the RMS enough information to calculate this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "RMS"? Do you mean *root mean squared error*? If so, what is the distribution of the errors, eg, is it normal? Is there an underlying trend? Is there seasonality? What is the nature of those aspects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately, RMS does not give you enough information.  It is simply the root mean square of the difference between points and the mean.

You could get an RMS value of 2 by having a signal which is constant except for 1 point out of 1000 which is is sqrt(4000) different.  Or you could have a continuous wave such as sin(t) with an amplitude of 2*sqrt(2).

In the first case, it is very likely to have consecutive equal numbers, but in the second you would never even get 2.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for your response!